Clarification Needed on Conditional Probability Problem
We have a family with four children. The probability of a baby being a boy is 0.5, and the gender is independent between births. We are asked to compute:
What is the probability that the family has two boys and two girls, given that the first (oldest) child is a boy?
Event A: The family has exactly two boys and two girls. Event B: The first child is a boy.
I attempted to calculate the conditional probability $P(A|B)$, where $P(B)=0.5$.
Next, I considered the fact that if the first child is a boy, then we need exactly one more boy and two girls among the three remaining children. There are three possible sequences (BGG, GBG, GGB): $P(A\cap B)=\binom{3}{1}\cdot(0.5)^3=0.375$.
Finally, I computed:
$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=0.75$, but the correct answer should be $0.375$.

Since you are given that the eldest child is a boy, rather than that there is at least one child that is a boy, you can ignore the oldest child.
The problem then reduces to computing the probability that of the three youngest children, exactly $~2~$ of them are girls.
Based on Binomial Distribution,
specifically the formula $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)},$
the probability is
$$\binom{3}{2} \times \left[ ~\dfrac{1}{2} ~\right]^2 \times \left[ ~\dfrac{1}{2} ~\right]^1 = \frac{3}{8}.$$

why you ignore the oldest child?

@BeNavon Because you are guaranteed that the child is a boy.  So, if you arrange the children in ascending order by age, since you know that the oldest child is a boy, you also know that the event that you are computing is that there are exactly $~2~$ girls among the $~3~$ youngest.  The situation is the same if you were given that one of the children was taller than the others, and this child was a boy. ...see next comment.

@BeNavon  Contrast this with the more limited information that one of the children is a boy, but there is no way of distinguishing this particular child from the other $~3~$ children.  Then, in this alternative problem, you have to examine the $~2^4~$ cases, and all that you can do is to eliminate the case of all $~4~$ children being girls.

If there are four children and two genders, there are $2^4=16$ possible combinations.
Of these, we can count the number of elements in $A\cap B$:
$BBGG, BGBG, BGGB$
so $P(A\cap B)=\frac{3}{16}$
As you correctly noted $P(B)=\frac{1}{2}$.
So $P(A|B)=\frac{3}{16}\div\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{8}$
Which is $0.375$
Edit
Where I think your calculation goes wrong is that when you calculated $P(A\cap B)$ you assumed the first born was $B$ therefore reducing the sample size to 8 rather than 16. Dividing by this probability was therefore unnecessary.
